# TFS Build Access to path Web.config is Denied

Tags: tfs

I am running into an issue when using a TFS build failing due to not being able to write to the Web.config file.  I have a Web.config transformation so I believe it is failing there.

I have compared my TFS build definition to a different project that is working and I do not see any differences.  The only thing I can think is that I renamed the TFS project before checking-in.... not sure if that could have caused the issue.

I am using TFS 2013 and Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the TransformXML beforeBuild from my csproj file.